# Bukkit - commands shows in chat after typed

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I created plugin, that implements life points to your world. After using command, my chat shows corrent message... and this command.

[image]

My code for this command looks like this.

```
        if(sender instanceof Player){
            if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(cmd1)){
                // player.sendMessage("CMD" + playerName);
                // Logic AddLife
                if(plugin.getConfig().getInt(playerName) >= 0){
                    lives = plugin.getConfig().getInt(playerName) + 1;

                    plugin.getConfig().set(playerName, lives);
                    plugin.saveConfig();

                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "You increased your life points by 1!");
                }
                else{
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You need life crystal to do this.");
                }

            }
            else{
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Only players can execute this command.");
            }
        }
        return true;
```

I don't want to see that command in chat. How to fix that?

Edit:
My main class that i called command method:

```
 @Override
    public void onEnable() {

        // Config
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new OnPlayerDeath(), this);
        getCommand("addlife").setExecutor(new AddLife());

        loadConfig();
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a problem that is elsewhere in your code, could we see the rest of the code for this command?

Comment: That's all my method responsible for addlife command. Besides of imports etc

Comment: Okay, so where is this method called? My guess is that you've added a player.sendMessage(command) somewhere for debugging that you haven't removed

Comment: Perhaps you did something wrong in your ``bukkit.yml``. Did you specified an Usage for your command?

Comment: I think i fix it. The problem is in if statement. I changed .equalsIgnoreCase() to .equals. Then method return false not true.

Comment: If your onCommand() method returns false, it will tell the player the command usage from the plugin.yml